# C++ file cfx_pmta.cxx won't compile

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the PMTA cfx_pmta.cxx file so I can make some changes but I can't get it to compile before I have even made any changes.

Here are the includes at the to of the file:

```
#if defined(sun)
    #define _POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    #define strcasecmp _stricmp
    #define strncasecmp _strnicmp
    #if defined(UNIT_TEST)
        #define __dllexport
    #else
        #define __dllexport __declspec(dllexport)
    #endif
#else
    #define __dllexport
    #define __cdecl
#endif

#ifdef __unix__
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <errno.h>
#endif

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#if defined _WIN32
    #include <time.h>   
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cfx.h"

#include "include/submitter/PmtaMsg.h"
#include "include/submitter/PmtaConn.h"
#include "include/submitter/PmtaRcpt.h"
```

229     Error C2079 'tmp' uses undefined class 'std::basic_ostringstream,std::allocator>'

230     Error   C2297   '<<': illegal, right operand has type 'const char [9]'

230     Error   C3861   'time': identifier not found

230     Warning C4552   '<<': operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect

231     Error   C2228   left of '.str' must have class/struct/union

```
229     std::ostringstream tmp; 
230     tmp << "boundary" << time(0);
231     std::string boundary = tmp.str();
```

617    Error    C2079   'f' uses undefined class 'std::basic_ifstream>'

617    Error    C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'int'

625    Error    C2228   left of '.read' must have class/struct/union

626    Error    C2228   left of '.gcount' must have class/struct/union

629    Error    C2228   left of '.close' must have class/struct/union

621    Error    C4996   'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

```
604 void
605 attachFile(const std::string& boundary, const char* fileName) {
606     addBoundary(boundary);
607     addData("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n");
608     addData("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"");
609     addData(fileName);  addData("\"\n");
610     addData("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n");
611
612     if (!PmtaMsgSetEncoding(_message, PmtaMsgENCODING_BASE64)) {
613         die("error setting base64 encoding", PmtaMsgGetLastError(_message));
614     }
615
616     char buffer[8192];
617     std::ifstream f(fileName);
618
619    if (!f) {
620        std::string error = std::string("error opening ") + fileName;
621        die(error, strerror(errno));
622    }
623
624    while (f) {
625        f.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
626        addData(buffer, static_cast<int>(f.gcount()));
627    }
628
629 f.close();
630
631    if (!PmtaMsgSetEncoding(_message, PmtaMsgENCODING_8BIT)) {
632        die("error setting 8-bit encoding", PmtaMsgGetLastError(_message));
633    }
634 }
```

736    Error    C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
736    Error    C2144   syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'

```
733 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
734 //  externally visible tag processor
735//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
736 extern "C" __dllexport void __cdecl
737 ProcessTagRequest(CCFXRequest* request) {
738     try {
739        TagProcessor proc(request);
740        proc.process();
741    }
742    catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
743        request->ThrowException(TAG_ERROR, "out of memory");
744    }
745    catch (char* text) {
746        // this may be thrown by some dummy classes
747        request->ThrowException(TAG_ERROR, text);
748    }
749    catch (CCFXException* e) {
750        request->ReThrowException(e);
751    }
752    catch (...) {
753    // original ColdFusion example comment:
754    // "Catch ALL other exceptions and throw them as Cold Fusion exceptions
755    // (DO NOT REMOVE! -- this prevents the server from crashing in case of
756    // an unexpected exception)"
757    request->ThrowException(TAG_ERROR, "Unexpected error occurred "\
758                             "while processing tag.");
759 }
760 };
```

Any help would be a great!! Just need to be able to get it to compile the DLL and then I can make the changes needed.

Also I'm not a C++ dev so trying to get my head round it, so go easy.

Comment: What part of "undefined class 'std::basic_ostringstream,std::allocator>'" you're having trouble understanding?

Comment: What is confusing is that I already have a include for <iostream> and so why would ostringstream be undefined?

Comment: because it's not defined in <iostream>. It's defined in <sstream>

Answer (score 0):

std::cout is a output stream which is defined within the `<iostream>` header.
in order to use std::string objects you have to include the `<string>` header

Try adding:

    `#include<iostream>
    #include<string>`

In your cxx file.

Comment: Sorry, had added the includes in question now

Comment: You are probably compiling file as a C file in order to be able to export DLL functions. In this case you cannot use iostream and (probably) throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading I decided to try the Command Line compiler and to my amazement it compiled fine.

So if anyone is intrested in how to recompile the cfx_pmta.cxx file for PMTA to change the Cold Fusion custom tag code run the following command (obviously changing *path* to match your file locat

```
cl /LD /MT /EHsc /IC:\path\api\include /IC:\ColdFusion8\include /D "_WIN32" C:\path\api\cfx_pmta.cxx /link C:\path\api\lib\pmta.lib ws2_32.lib advapi32.lib
```